# Microsoft Exchange REST API write calendar event with POST from Powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, office365api

I tried to access the calendars of my Exchange 2016 CU5 environment via REST-API using Powershell. GET methods are working fine with no errors, but now I tried to write a calendar event with POST method and it won't work. Here's my code:

```
$cred = Get-Credential

$url = "https://myexchangeserver.de/api/v2.0/me/events"

$content = "application/json"

$body = "{
  ""Event"": {
  ""Subject"": ""Testtermin REST"",
  ""Body"": {
    ""ContentType"": ""HTML"",
    ""Content"":""Testtermin REST""
  },
  ""Start"": {
  ""DateTime"": ""2017-10-10T16:00:00"",
  ""TimeZone"": ""Europe/Berlin""
  },
  ""End"": {
  ""DateTime"": ""2017-10-10T16:30:00"",
  ""TimeZone"": ""Europe/Berlin""
  },
  ""Attendees"": [
{
  ""EmailAddress"": {
    ""Address"": ""otto.outlooktest@hft-stuttgart.de"",
    ""Name"": ""Otto Outlooktest""
  },
  ""Type"": ""Required""
}
  ]
}}"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Credential $cred -ContentType $content -Body $body
```

I put this into a .ps1 file and execute it within my Exchange Management Shell.

It opens a popup-windows to let me enter my credentials, but afterwards I always get a error message "400 invalid request".

I already tried several writings, but always the same.

Anyone got a idea what's wrong?

Greetings, Michael

Comment: Have you tried running it without the credentials? For eg, by logging in as an Exchange Admin or from a Run As window? That way we can eliminate possibilities

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you get rid of Event: as that isn't need (eg just check any of the documentation samples or Graph Explorer samples). Also if you use fiddler to capture one of your requests and look at the full response that comes back from the server it will generally tell you what in particular is wrong with the request that is being sent.

Comment: I tried it with fiddler, all I got ist the following: An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected. REST APIs for this mailbox are currently in preview. You can find more information about the preview REST APIs at https://dev.outlook.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The REST API doesn't like IANA Timezones. Instead of "Europe/Berlin" I put in "W. Europe Standard Time".
Greetings,
Michael